# How to know if object is a singleton in Kotlin?

Tags: object, reflection, kotlin, singleton, tostring

I would like to define `toString()`in superclass so, that it detects that class instance is a singleton (an `object`) and print its name.

Is it possible in Kotlin?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 2):

The following [`objectInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/object-instance.html) property of [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html) can be helpful:

```
/**
 * The instance of the object declaration, or `null` if this class is not an object declaration.
 */
public val objectInstance: T?
```

Here's an example:

```
object Singleton

println(Singleton::class.objectInstance) // xx.Singleton@77a57272
println(""::class.objectInstance) //null
```